# Cauchy convergence criteria

Tags: sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

I was reading about convergence of a series and there is a part regarding Cauchy convergence criteria and there is an equivalence I don't understand. What I don't understand is why for $n\ge m \ge N$ this:$$\sum_{k=m}^n a_k \lt \epsilon $$ is equivalent to this: $$\lim_{n\to\infty,m\to\infty} \sum_{k=n}^{n+m}a_k = 0$$

Comment: This equivalence is just the definition of the limit. Maybe recalling that will solve your problem.

Comment: The two statements you wrote are not equivalent. You left out all the key quantifiers in the first one.

Comment: if they are not equivalent, at least I would like to understand the second formula the upper limit of the sum I don't understand why it has to be $n+m$

Comment: This is the link of what I read regarding cauchy criterion convegence. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergent_series